# Is there any limit that application state can store ??

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any limit that application state in asp.net can store ?? 
Am trying to know the limit so that I can avoid any slow on my application performance.

Comment: I think it's like with every other object in .Net, until you get `OutOfMemoryException`. But you probably won't to stop way before memory leak...

Comment: How would knowing the limit help you avoid performance problems? Simple answer... use common sense when deciding what to store in session. If it becomes a problem then switch to a different state server (like SQL Server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Resources:   Because it is stored in memory, application state is very fast compared to saving data to disk or a database. **However, storing large blocks of data in application state can fill up server memory**, causing the server to page memory to disk. As an alternative to using application state, you can use the ASP.NET cache mechanism for storing large amounts of application data. The ASP.NET cache also stores data in memory and is therefore very fast; however, ASP.NET actively manages the cache and will remove items when memory becomes scarce. For more information see ASP.NET Caching Overview.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) (emphasis added).